# OOP Design, Calling Certain Methods Outside of a Main Class

Tags: java, class, oop, parameter-passing

In my class, we are to create a project with several Main classes and shared classes. In one specific main class, called `UserApp`, I create an object of the class `UserInterface`, which deals **directly** with a file, called Log.txt.

I create an object of the class,`DataStorage` inside of `UserApp`, which I use to call a method that returns a String value back to `UserApp`. I then take that string value and pass it to a method in `UserInterface` which will write to the file Log.txt. For Example:

```
public class UserApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();

        String[] commands = ui.readCommandLine();

        while(!ui.isFileEnd()){

            switch(command[0]){
            case "LI":  ui.displayThis(dataStorage.listById());
            break;
            case "QI":  ui.displayThis(dataStorage.queryById(command[0]));
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DataStorage {
    public String queryById(String id) {
        // Stuff the method does goes here

        return stringToReturn;
    }
}
```

To me, this seems like the most OOP way of doing things. I emailed her and asked her if this was the correct use. She said to call `ui.displayThis` inside of the `listById()` in `DataStorage`... that would mean that I need to either create a `UserInterface` object inside the `DataStorage` class, or pass the `DataStorage` object in as a parameter to `listById()`. If I did it like she said, the method `listById()` wouldn't return a string, but would be void. For Example:

```
public class UserApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] commands = ui.readCommandLine();

        while(!ui.isFileEnd()){

            switch(command[0]){
            case "LI":  dataStorage.listById(); // Here is the difference
            break;
            case "QI":  dataStorage.queryById(command[0]); // And here
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DataStorage {
    public void queryById(String id) {
        UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();
        // Stuff the method does goes here

        ui.displayThis(stringToDisplay);
    }
}
```

There are more switch statements and methods but I felt they were unnecessary to show for this question. I've done some research on this, and from what I've gathered, I'm not sure that this is a style preference or if one way is better than the other. the way she wants me to do it just doesn't feel right with an OOP language. Which method would *actually* be correct for OOP design?

Edit: The second part would actually be passing in a UserInterface object as a parameter. This seems to make more sense then creating the object each time. Would `this` be a better way to do it?

Comment: Side note: the cases in a `switch` statement fall through, so the way you've written it, an `"LI"` command will perform both the `"LI"` and `"QI"` actions.  Use `break;` if that's not what you want.

Comment: If we follow the `Model-View-Controller (MVC)`-principle, where `DataStorage` in the `Model`, `UserInterface` the `View`, and `UserApp` the `Controller`, then under no circumstances should `DataStorage` call the `UserInterface`, or even know that it exists. MVC is such an old principle that I would expect even teachers to know it. But I guess not...

Comment: Your instructor's solution is pretty ludicrous. Exposing all the GUI internals, and having *them* be the API between a data layer and the UI layer is very uncommon.

Comment: @ajb ah, my mistake. I'll add the edit. Thank you.

Comment: For one, doing the second way properly would require having a stable-ish set of GUI operations to be done with data. As opposed to your way, where the API is a set of possible ways to query manipulate available data. From experience, the latter tends to be a much more predictable (mostly boilerplate) and stable set of functionality - your model changes way less than your UI.

Comment: Last, but not least, if you're being pedantic neither is "truly OO". For that you'd want to follow the SOLID principles. (Where things like design patterns are a way to comply with those, not an end unto itself.) Starting with S (the *single responsibility principle*), `UserApp` does too many things in both designs. (Reads user input, detects commands in it, as well as dispatches them.) Pedantic OO would have a class to read user input from "somewhere", pass it on to a black box accepting lines of input to process, which would then call appropriate command objects etc.

Comment: In that (admittedly bloated) design it'd be most likely the command objects' job to connect the UI and the data layer - neither would directly access the other, and both would have an API exposed to the command layer.

Comment: @millimoose That makes sense, but for assignment sake this is what the classes jobs are. I totally agree with you though, I feel like this could all be re-done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should know is that both ways of doing it would "work", meaning that you'd accomplish what you set out to do, which is to retrieve something from data storage and display it in the UI.

However, getting something to just "work" isn't always best.  In real world applications, engineers such as myself are concerned with maintainability.  Simply put, maintainability means that at some point in the future, I may have to come back in to this piece of code and add functionality, or change the way something works (vs. something like a school project where you write the code, submit it, and then never see it or use it again).  If I've got a well-written component that has dependencies on other components only where they're necessary, then I can modify and test the said component easily and be confident that I'm not changing the behavior of other components.

So back to your question - the first method that you proposed has a DataStorage class with one method, queryById, that takes a parameter and returns a value.  It doesn't have any dependencies on a display component.  This is the correct method of structuring your code in my opinion.  The fewer dependencies, the better -- it's easier to maintain, and it's easier to write tests for.  If you don't believe me, try to write a unit test using JUnit or another testing framework for both ways of implementing the queryById method -- you'll find that your method is simpler to test because you don't have to mock out or inject or create an instance of the UI component.

Comment: Ok, that is basically what I was thinking too. Thank you, very informative.

Comment: I don't agree: you don't write tests for methods, you write tests for features of your application.  Moving things to your main method makes them even harder to test.

Comment: @herman You might be confusing unit testing with acceptance / integration testing. The clue is in the name: unit testing tests basic *units* of code, in isolation. This is easier the less coupling there is between those units.

Comment: 1. No I'm not.  Contrary to popular belief, in TDD, a unit test is not a test for a specific method/class.  It is a test that runs in isolation from other tests (i.e. no side effects on other tests possible).  Integration tests are tests that cross ports (such as DB access, web service calls etc.)  There's a good talk by Ian Cooper on Vimeo where he explains how most people are interpreting/doing TDD wrong: http://vimeo.com/68375232
2. How would you "unit test" (according to your definition) the logic that was moved to the main method?

Answer (score 3):

With the information you've given, it seems that the first way is designed to be more flexible. Rarely do professionals write systems where the storage layer talks directly to the UI layer.

Your first example seems to follow the MVC pattern. The second example seems to be more like the GoF Command pattern.

Either will work, it's just a question of maintainability.

However, OO design is all about separating concerns of the overall program into smaller cohesive units.

Comment: I'll have to look more into MVC and GoF. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd be fine with having `listById` be a void function that does the displaying (instead of returning a `String`) ... **but** I'd do it something like this:

```
public interface DisplayMethod {
    public void display (String s);
}

public class DataStorage {
    public void queryById(String id, DisplayMethod displayer) {
        // UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();  DELETE THIS LINE
        // Stuff the method does goes here

        displayer.display(stringToDisplay);
    }
}
```

and in `UserApp`:

```
final UserInterface ui = new UserInterface();

...

DisplayMethod displayer = new DisplayMethod () {
    public void display (String s) 
        { ui.displayThis (s); }
};

...

case "QI":  dataStorage.queryById(command[0], displayer);
```

Or something similar.  (You'd have to add `final` to the declaration of `ui`.)  The effect here is that you can still make `queryById` be a void function (which is useful if it's going to display more than one string), but you don't hard-wire the information about *how* to do the displaying into `DataStorage`, since it really doesn't belong there.  Your instinct that the stuff to deal with the `UserInterface` should be in one place, rather than spread out over several classes, is a very good one.  Congratulations.  (P.S. I'm not claiming that `DisplayMethod` is a good name.  Naming things is one of my weak points.)

Comment: I think you want to delete the line in `queryById` that calls the `UserInterface` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

#### What I don't like about your teacher's solution

Querying something from a data store and writing to a file (which is apparently the applications user interface) are two separate things, and your `queryById` method shouldn't do both.  The fact that you create a `UserInterface` object in that method makes it even worse, but that could be solved by passing it in the constructor and storing it in a (`final`) field.

The reason your teacher is suggesting this, is probably because she favors the **Tell, Don't Ask** principle.  See Martin Fowler's Bliki for a good explanation of this principle: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html  He also explains why he doesn't use it.  As you correctly observed: your `queryById` method wouldn't return a value.  Actually then by definition it wouldn't be a query method anymore, but query methods aren't always bad.

#### What I suggest

Your `DataStore` class represents the **model**, your `UserInterface` class represents the **view**.  Start from your first solution, add another class to represent the **controller**, which calls the `DataStore` and `UserInterface`, both of which are passed in the constructor by your `main` method, which is otherwise empty.  Due to the fact that the logic is now in the controller instead of the `main` method, it is testable (probably needing [Test Doubles](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) for both the `DataStore` and the `UserInterface`).

Comment: "Tell Don't Ask" would work fine in this case, without coupling, if we *told* the DataStorage what to do via an interface object.  Either the teacher in this case doesn't understand how to use the principle correctly, or this is actually a class where most of the students are well behind our OP and their heads would explode if they had to use complicated stuff like callbacks.

Comment: It's a mid-level undergraduate CS class, so maybe. Lol

Comment: @ajb I still think that writing the result on a data store a query method is simpler and better: after all you're not asking for any private details of the class, you're asking for the exact same information that it would share via the callback anyway.  Actually, there's not much difference between telling someone to tell you something, and asking.